# How to Sort a list of strings and find the 1000 most common values in java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

In java (either using external libraries or not) I need to take a list of approximately 500,000 values and find the most frequently occurring (mode) 1000. Doing my best to keep the complexity to a minimum.

What I've tried so far, make a hash, but I can't because it would have to be backwards key=count value =string, otherwise when getting the top 1000, my complexity will be garbage. and the backwards way doesn't really work great because I would be having a terrible complexity for insertion as I search for where my string is to be able to remove it and insert it one higher...

I've tried using a binary search tree, but that had the same issue of what the data would be for sorting, either on the count or the string. If it's on the string then getting the count for the top 1000 is bad, and vice versa insertion is bad.

I could sort the list first (by string) and then iterate over the list and keep a count until it changes strings. but what data structure should I use to keep track of the top 1000?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I would first create a `Map<String, Long>` to store the frequency of each word. Then, I'd sort this map by value in descending order and finally I'd keep the first `1000` entries.

In code:

```
List<String> top1000Words = listOfWords.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(1000)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You might find it cleaner to separate the above into 2 steps: first collecting to the map of frequencies and then sorting its entries by value and keeping the first 1000 entries.

Comment: There should be a daily prize for "most hardcore Java 8 answer".

Comment: @Brian :P Then we would always be beaten by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

Answer (score 3):

I'd separate this into three phases:

- Count word occurrences (e.g. by using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`)
- Sort the results (e.g. by converting the map into a list of entries and ordering by value descending)
- Output the top 1000 entries of the sorted results

The sorting will be slow if the counts are small (e.g. if you've actually got 500,000 separate words) but if you're expecting lots of duplicate words, it should be fine.

Comment: If the amount of distinct items is clearly larger than available RAM, [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) gives an estimate.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by converting the map into a list of entries

Comment: @yankelh: Well you get the entry set from the map, and you create a list from it... each entry is a key/value pair.

Comment: @9000: With a maximum of 500,000 entries, I'd be surprised if that overwhelmed things. (I guess if the strings are huge...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: If it's the only task you're running on a modern desktop, then yes! If it's another auxiliary task among many in an already busy game running on a lower-end Android phone, it depends...

Answer (score 1):

I have had this question open for a few days now and have decided to rebel against Federico's elegant Java 8 answer and submit the least Java 8 answer possible.

The following code makes use of a helper class that associates a tally with a string.

```
public class TopOccurringValues {
    static HashMap<String, StringCount> stringCounts = new HashMap<>();

    // set low for demo.  Change to 1000 (or whatever)
    static final int TOP_NUMBER_TO_COLLECT = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // load your strings in here
        List<String> strings = loadStrings();

        // tally up string occurrences
        for (String string: strings) {
            StringCount stringCount = stringCounts.get(string);
            if (stringCount == null) {
                stringCount = new StringCount(string);
            }
            stringCount.increment();
            stringCounts.put(string, stringCount);
        }

        // sort which have most
        ArrayList<StringCount> sortedCounts = new ArrayList<>(stringCounts.values());
        Collections.sort(sortedCounts);

        // collect the top occurring strings
        ArrayList<String> topCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        int upperBound = Math.min(TOP_NUMBER_TO_COLLECT, sortedCounts.size());
        System.out.println("string\tcount");
        for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i++) {
            StringCount stringCount = sortedCounts.get(i);
            topCollection.add(stringCount.string);
            System.out.println(stringCount.string + "\t" + stringCount.count);
        }
    }

    // in this demo, strings are randomly generated numbers.
    private static List<String> loadStrings() {
        Random random = new Random(1);
        ArrayList<String> randomStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
            randomStrings.add(String.valueOf(Math.round(random.nextGaussian() * 1000)));
        }
        return randomStrings;
    }

    static class StringCount implements Comparable<StringCount> {
        int count = 0;
        String string;
        StringCount(String string) {this.string = string;}
        void increment() {count++;}
        @Override
        public int compareTo(StringCount o) {return o.count - count;}
    }
}
```

55 lines of code!  It's like reverse code golf.  The String generator creates 5 million strings instead of 500,000 because: why not?

```
string  count
-89 2108
70  2107
77  2085
-4  2077
36  2077
65  2072
-154    2067
-172    2064
194 2063
-143    2062
```

The randomly generated strings can have values between -999 and 999 but because we are getting gaussian values, we will see numbers with higher scores that are closer to 0.

Comment: Hi! Upvoted :D It's a nice solution, though I think putting the `StringCount` instance again in the map is not needed (1 less line of code, happy you :D)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the java stream API :

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "aa"});

// First we compute a map of word -> occurrences
final Map<String, Long> collect = input.stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

// Here we sort the map and collect the first 1000 entries
final List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> entries = new ArrayList<>(collect.entrySet());
final List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> result = entries.stream()
                                                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                                                    .limit(1000)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution I chose to use was to first make a hash map with key value pairs as . I got the count by iterating over a linked list, and inserting the key value pair, Before insertion I would check for existence and if so increase the count. That part was quite straight forward.

The next part where I needed to sort it according to it's value, I used a library called guava published by google and it was able to make it very easy to sort by value instead of key using what they called a multimap. where they in a sense reverse the hash, and allow multiple values to be mapped to one key, so that I can have all my top 1000, opposed to some solutions mentioned above which didn't allow that, and would cause me to just get one value per key.

The last step was to iterate over the multimap (backwards) to get the 1000 most frequent occurrences.

Have a look at the code of the function if you're interested

```
private static void FindNMostFrequentOccurences(ArrayList profileName,int n) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        //iterate through our data 
        for(int i = 0; i< profileName.size(); i++){

            String current_id = profileName.get(i).toString();
            if(hmap.get(current_id) == null){
                hmap.put(current_id, 1);
            } else {
                int current_count = hmap.get(current_id);
                current_count += 1;
                hmap.put(current_id, current_count);
            }
        }
        ListMultimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        hmap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            multimap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (!multimap.isEmpty()){
                int lastKey = Iterables.getLast(multimap.keys());               
                String lastValue = Iterables.getLast(multimap.values());
                multimap.remove(lastKey, lastValue);
                System.out.println(i+1+": "+lastValue+", Occurences: "+lastKey);
            }
        }
    }
```